# Listing files "*.vhdl" submitted by user "tom" in the P4 repo

Tags: perforce, p4v

I 'm looking for a P4 command which does a wildcard search across P4 dirs of interest to me

Eg: Our P4 repo looks like as below:

> //depot/chip/block/foo_a1/...
>
> //depot/chip/block/1_foo_a2/...
>
> //depot/chip/block/2_foo_a3/...
>
> //depot/chip/block/nop_a1/...
>
> //depot/chip/block/1_nop_a2/...

I'm looking for a command that looks for all files with '*.vhdl' submitted by user 'tom' in P4 repos '//depot/chip/block/*foo*/...' I 'm not interested in other repos.

Answer (score 1):

```
p4 -Ztag -F "//depot/chip/block/*foo*/...@=%change%" changes -u tom "//depot/chip/block/*foo*/..." | p4 -x - files
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the intent for -Ztag and -F. The command doesn't seem to work. All I need is to find certain types of files in certain P4 repos checked in by a certain user. When executed the above command, all I get on stdout is 'p4: No match'

Comment: I'm using P4 in Linux. Looks like in the above command the '*' is not resolved

Comment: Your shell might require you to quote arguments that contain "*".  I'll add the double quotes to my answer so you can see where they go.